# Why is this soln faster than the other?

Tags: c++, arrays, hashmap, unordered-map

The problem is Leetcode's N-Repeated Element in Size 2N Array

> In a array A of size 2N, there are N+1 unique elements, and exactly one of these elements is repeated N times.

Return the element repeated N times.

I'm confused Please help!

**Faster code**

```
    class Solution {
public:
    int repeatedNTimes(vector<int>& A) {
        auto it = A.begin();
        while(it!=A.end())
        {
            if(count(A.begin(),A.end(),*it)>1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
                it++;              
        }
        return *it;
    }
};
```

**Slower code**

```
    class Solution {
public:
    int repeatedNTimes(vector<int>& A) {
        unordered_map<int,int> u;
        int rep;
        for(auto i: A){
            u[i]++;
            if(u[i]>1){
                rep=i;
            }
        }
        
        return rep;
    }
};
```

Comment: Neither solution seems optimal, but one advantage of the first is that it quits looking as soon as it finds a solution. That improvement could easily be added to the second, why don't you try it.

Comment: Insertion/lookup in a `unordered_map` may be in constant time on average, but that doesn't mean it doesn't take a considerable amount of time (compared to other operations). In this case it's slower for the given input set than the other solution even though the time complexity of that solution is worse. Btw: the second solition counts the frequencies for all elements, even if an element with more than 1 occurance has been found; doing 2 lookups when one would be sufficient doesn't help either; furthermore a `unordered_set` would also do the trick.

Comment: @john thank you for your reply but then what would be its optimal soln?

Comment: @fabian yes i do understand now `unordered_map` will take more time inserting the elements. thank you for your reply!

Comment: @doggone_boy I've changed my mind. Given that 50% of the elements are repeated, two the repeated elements must either be adjacent, or the repeated element must alternate over the whole array. You can check for both of those possibilities with a single scan of the whole array. That's a linear time algorithm even in the worst case and doesn't require any additional data structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some (untested) code using the method described above. I do assume that the input data is in the form described. If that is not the case this code will error.

```
class Solution
{
public:
    int repeatedNTimes(vector<int>& A) {
        // check for alternating elements at even indexes
        if (A[0] == A[2])
           return A[0];
        // check for alternating elements at odd indexes
        if (A[1] == A[3])
           return A[1];
        // check for first and last being the same
        if (A.front() == A.back())
           return A.front();
        // check adjacent elements
        for (size_t i = 0;; ++i)
        {
            if (A[i] == A[i + 1])
                return A[i];
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

EDIT

Thought of a bug, my algorithm only works if adjacency wraps around, that is the first and last elements are also considered adjacent. I've added code to check for that possibility as well.

Comment: Your entire for loop could be a call to `std::adjacent_find`.

Comment: @john this solution is really faster! Thanks man!

Comment: @DrewDormann can you explain what it does? thanks!

Comment: @doggone_boy not in these comments, sorry.  This isn't the place to ask a new question.

Comment: @doggone_boy `std::adjacent_find` does pretty much what my loop does. It looks for adjacent equal elements and returns an iterator to the first such element it finds.